# How to take average between NaN values?

Tags: python, average, nan

I have a simple list that contains numbers and `NaN` values. Is there a way to take the `AVG` between two `NaN` values? an example could be like this:

```
list = [NaN, 5, 6, 7, NaN, NaN, NaN, 6, 2, 8, 5, 4, NaN, NaN]
```

and I would expect an output like

```
Output = [6,5]
```

Comment: how can you take an AVG from two NAN values ?

Comment: shouldn't the average of any 1D list be 1 element only ?

Comment: Can you explain better your question? How can the average outputs a list of two components? What are you expecting from that output?

Comment: @Tamil Selvan they mean the average *between* the Nan values not of them

Comment: By "average" do you mean the mean, median or mode, or some other average?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `groupby` from `itertools` -

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
NaN = np.nan
lst = [NaN, 5, 6, 7, NaN, NaN, NaN, 6, 2, 8, 5, 4, NaN, NaN]
[np.mean(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x is not NaN) if k]
# [6.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: You can avoid numpy by using the built-in `import statistics; statistics.mean(...)`

Answer (score 1):

A simple method requiring no additional skills:

```
import numpy as np

## NaN is assumed to be pre-defined by the users, e.g.: NaN = np.nan or NaN = float('nan')

def get_mean_between_nan(ar):
    out = list()
    t = list()
    for x in ar:
        if np.isnan(x):
            if len(t) > 0:
                out.append(np.mean(t))
                t = list()
        else:
            t.append(x)
    if len(t) > 0:
        out.append(np.mean(t))
    return out
```

Comment: No additional packages except numpy! :)

Comment: `np.isnan(NaN)` will throw a `NameError` on `NaN`

Comment: NaN is not a standard identifier for ``not a number''. It should be first defined by the users.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30825549/1021819, first split the list into a chunked list-of-lists:

```py
NaN=None # or np.nan, float('nan'), 'nan' or any other separator value you like = even '/'
my_list = [NaN, 5, 6, 7, NaN, NaN, NaN, 6, 2, 8, 5, 4, NaN, NaN]

from itertools import groupby
chunks = list(list(g) for k,g in groupby(my_list, key=lambda x: x is not NaN) if k))
# [[5, 6, 7], [6, 2, 8, 5, 4]]
```

Then you can use the built-in `statistics.mean()` as follows:

```py
import statistics
output = [statistics.mean(chunk) for chunk in chunks]
# [6, 5]
```

There you go.

Notes:

1. No need for `numpy`. But if you do want a pure `numpy` solution you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/31863171/1021819
2. Don't use `list` for your variable name since it is the name of a built-in type!